# Qt: hiding then showing QQuickView prevents future mouse events

Tags: c++, qt, qml, qtquick2

I have a QQuickView I've embedded over another widget using createWindowContainer().

```
quickView = new QQuickView(...);
container = new QWidget();
createWindowContainer(quickView, container);
```

Then I add the container widget to the widget that's inside the window.

```
layout = new QVBoxLayout();
fullWindowWidget->setLayout(layout);
layout->addWidget(container);
```

This seems to work fine render-wise but it seems like the QQuickView QML scene doesn't handle mouse events if I hide then show the container.  If I launch the app with the container visible, it handles the mouse events fine.  But if I start with the container hidden and show the container, any clicks on the container seem to be bubbled up to the widget behind it.  Does hiding the container put the QQuickView in a strange state that prevents clicks even when it's visible again?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like I was calling `grabMouse()` on the main window.  Calling `releaseMouse()` before showing the container seemed to fix it.